Is IMPORTHTML in SHEETS not working anymore?

=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://www.naturalstattrick.com/playerteams.php?fromseason=20212022&thruseason=20232024&stype=2&sit=5v5&score=all&stdoi=std&rate=y&team=ALL&pos=S&loc=B&toi=0&gpfilt=none&fd=&td=&tgp=410&lines=single&draftteam=ALL","Table",1),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col33,Col14")
So for a year this has worked, but all of a sudden it's now saying "Could not fetch". Is there also anyway I can get the same data using ImportXML?

About your situation, I confirmed the same situation. It seems that IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML cannot be used for your URL. But, fortunately, when I tested your URL using UrlFetchApp of Google Apps Script, I confirmed that the HTML can be obtained. In this answer, I would like to propose a sample script for retrieving your expected values.
Sample script:
Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. And, please set the sheet name you want to put the values. Also, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services. In this sample, the HTML table is parsed using Sheets API. I think that the Sheets API as a parser for HTML tables is very strong. So, I used it.
By the way, in this script, from SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col33,Col14 in your formula, the columns [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 33, 14] are retrieved. If you want to change it, please modify columns.
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://www.naturalstattrick.com/playerteams.php?fromseason=20212022&thruseason=20232024&stype=2&sit=5v5&score=all&stdoi=std&rate=y&team=ALL&pos=S&loc=B&toi=0&gpfilt=none&fd=&td=&tgp=410&lines=single&draftteam=ALL";
  const columns = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 33, 14];

  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).clearContents() || ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const html = res.getContentText();
  const table = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]*?<\/table>/)[0];
  const requests = { requests: [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: table, coordinate: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId() } } }] };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(requests, ss.getId());
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().map(r => columns.map(i => r[i - 1] || null));
  sheet.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}

Testing:
When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

Another approach:
As another approach, when each value is retrieved by regex, it becomes as follows. In this case, this script can be used as a s custom function.
Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script.
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const table = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]*?<\/table>/);
  const tr = [...table[0].matchAll(/<tr>[\w\s\S]*?<\/tr>/g)];
  const td = tr.map(e =>
    [...e[0].matchAll(/<t(h|d).*?>([\w\s\S]*?)<\/t(h|d)>/g)].map(f => {
      const t = f[2].match(/<a.*?>([\w\s\S]*?)<\/a>/);
      return t ? t[1] : f[2];
    })
  );
  return td;
}

When you use this script, please put the following formula into a cell. By this, the same result as the above can be obtained.
=QUERY(SAMPLE("https://www.naturalstattrick.com/playerteams.php?fromseason=20212022&thruseason=20232024&stype=2&sit=5v5&score=all&stdoi=std&rate=y&team=ALL&pos=S&loc=B&toi=0&gpfilt=none&fd=&td=&tgp=410&lines=single&draftteam=ALL"),"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col33,Col14")

References:

fetch(url)
PasteDataRequest of Sheets API

